# How to create JSON format with group by and count functions in mysql?

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I need to get count of group by key as an array of json.

**table:**

```
designation      | name  
------------------------
Engineer         | Ben      
Sr.Engineer      | Tom      
Lead Engineer    | Dan
Engineer         | Michle
```

**output that I need:**

### grouped_data

```
[{designation:"Engineer",count:2},{designation:"Sr.Engineer",count:1}, {designation:"Lead Engineer",count:1}]
```

I tried

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('designation', designation,  'total_users', count(*) as total_users)) as user_spit_up
FROM user group by designation
```

But its getting error

> Invalid use of group function.

Help please.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this was the solution that worked for me.
For your problem it would be something like this:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(a.array_counts)
FROM (SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
                     'designation', designation,
                     'total_users', COUNT(designation)
                 ) array_counts
      FROM user
      GROUP BY designation
     ) a
```